# nav dropdown color css not working on mobile devices or small screen devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i have added background in my bootstrap navbar dropdown menu, it's working completely fine on big screen devices, but on small screen devices like mobile phone the background colors become transparent and the menu overlaps my content

```
  .nav-dropdown {
    background: #fff;
    @include border-radius($popover);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25),0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.35);
    border: none;
    top: 134%;
```

is there anyway to make the dropdown background be same on small screen devices.

**Edit**

I tried Chandra kumar answer but it doesn't worked out:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

  body {
    padding-top: 67px;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
  }
  nav.navbar {
    padding: 5px 0;
    .filter-links {
      margin-top: 16px;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  .nav-dropdown {
    background: #fff;
}
    #logo {
      width: 138px;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .new-post-button {
      display: inline-flex;
    }
  }
```

**Desktop View:**
[image: Desktop view]

**Mobile View Right Now** I want it to be exactly like desktop view
[image]

Comment: add code snippet in jsfiddle @AhmedRezaSiddique

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use media queries and add the classes you want to tweak

**For example:**

```
 /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
 @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
   .nav-dropdown {
      background: #fff;
   }
 }
```

For Bootstrap 3 default media queries you may found it [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)

Comment: thanks for replying, but unfortunately it doesn't worked, i have updated my questions with screen-shot of what is happening, please have a look @Chandra Kumar